# Build a Flux object in while cycle

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have an interesting problem which I don't know how to solve without calling a `block()` method.

1. my method receives a user as an argument.
2. it calls an external service and receives a Mono
3. if Mono does not contain an error and `user.getDepartment().startsWith("Development")` I want to add this to the Flux
4. Flux should be a result of my method

For now I unfortunatelly should initialize Flux from the list before calling the `block()`-method for Mono that I receive:

```
  Flux<User> getUsers(User user) {

     List<Users> developmentUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

     while (user.containsManager()) {

         val resultUser = externalUserServiceClient.getManager(user).block(); //externalUserServiceClient.getManager(user) should return a Mono<User>
         if (resultUser.getDepartment().startsWith("Development"))
             developemtnUsers.add(resultUser);
         user = resultUser;
     }

     return Flux.fromIterable(developmentUsers);
  }
```

I am sure there should be a way not to interrupt the async processes chain. Do you know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Mono#expand`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#expand-java.util.function.Function-) that recursively applies `getManager` function and combines results into `Flux<User>`:

```
Flux<User> getUsers(User user) {
  return getManager(user).expand(manager -> getManager(manager));
}

Mono<User> getManager(User user) {
  if (user.containsManager()) {
    return externalUserServiceClient.getManager(user)
      .filter(manager -> manager.getDepartment().startsWith("Development"));
  } else {
    return Mono.empty();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By using

```
externalUserServiceClient.getManager(user).map(manager -> ...);

//or

externalUserServiceClient.getManager(user).flatMap(manager -> ...);
```

Comment: how would you suggest to map 1. the `while`-condition 2. `if`-condition?